# Adding links to D3 axis labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d470qqe1/2/) as my example, my intentions are to make it such that clicking on the axis labels ( Group 1, Group 2, Group 3 ) would open the appropriate Links as specified in the data.

I've tried to rebind the data to the .ticks selection, but that only works for the first axis label.  Since only the name is passed to the axis mapping, I'm not sure how to retain the relation to add an on( 'click'... ) event to the label.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

```
    var data = [{
    "Items": [{
        "Value": 3327,
        "Name": {
            "Value": "A"
        },
    }, {
        "Value": 794,
        "Name": {
            "Value": "B"
        },
    }, {
        "Value": 1999,
        "Name": {
            "Value": "C"
        },
    }, ],
    "Type": "Group",
    "Name": {
        "Value": "Group 1"
    },
    "Link": "www.espn.com",
}, {
    "Items": [{
        "Value": 3317,
        "Name": {
            "Value": "A"
        },
    }, {
        "Value": 787,
        "Name": {
            "Value": "B"
        },
    }, {
        "Value": 2008,
        "Name": {
            "Value": "C"
        },
    }, ],
    "Type": "Group",
    "Name": {
        "Value": "Group 2"
    },
    "Link": "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
}, {
    "Items": [{
        "Value": 3290,
        "Name": {
            "Value": "A"
        },
    }, {
        "Value": 760,
        "Name": {
            "Value": "B"
        },
    }, {
        "Value": 2019,
        "Name": {
            "Value": "C"
        },
    }, ],
    "Type": "Group",
    "Name": {
        "Value": "Group 3"
    },
    "Link": "http://www.google.com",
}]

var variables = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

var width = 300;
var margin = {
    left: 100
};
var height = 300;

var y0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1);

var y1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width - margin.left]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y0)
.orient('left');

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', 0)');

y0.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.Name.Value;
}));
y1.domain(variables).rangeRoundBands([0, y0.rangeBand()]);
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d3.max(d.Items, function (d) {
        return d.Value;
    });
})]);

svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
    .call(yAxis);

var measures = svg.selectAll('.name')
.data(data)
.enter().append('g')
.attr('class', 'bar')
.attr('transform', function (d) {
    return 'translate(0, ' + y0(d.Name.Value) + ')';
});

measures.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function (d) {
    return d.Items;
})
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('height', y1.rangeBand() - 1)
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', function (d) {
    return y1(d.Name.Value)
})
    .attr('width', function (d) {
    return x(d.Value)
});


measures.selectAll('text')
    .data(function (d) {
    return d.Items;
})
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', function (d) {
    return y1(d.Name.Value) + y1.rangeBand() / 2
})
    .text(function (d) {
    if (d.Name.Value) {
        return d.Name.Value + ' - ' + d.Value;
    } else {
        return d.Value;
    }

})
    .attr('dy', '.35em')
    .style( 'fill', 'red' )
;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you were on the right track, under the hood as may have already realized d3.svg.axis binds the domain set on the scale as the data of the ticks i.e.

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y0)
```

and

```
y0.domain(data.map(function (d) {
  return d.Name.Value;
}));
```

Fortunately the `click` callback parameters are the datum itself (which in this case is `d.Name.Value`) and the index of the current `d.Name.Value`, therefore the same index could be used in `data` to get its link e.g.

```
d3.selectAll('.tick')
  .on('click', function (d, i) {
    console.log(data[i].Link)
  })
```

Comment: That's perfect.  And so obvious in hind sight.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Mauricio Poppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3341726/mauricio-poppe). Trying out your proposed solution, I found out at least with the latest version D3v6 that the first function parameter actually represents the mouse event. Your "d" was a little bit misleading to me, as I thought I could directly pass-in some "data". What worked for me is quite similar to your solution, but makes the standard D3 behaviour a little more clear, I guess:

```
  d3.selectAll('.tick')
    .data(data)
    .on('click', (e, d) => {
       console.log(e); // e is the mouse click event
       console.log(d.Link); // d references the iterator object of data
     })
```